# Cut a polygon into 4 parts with equals area. java

Tags: java, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry, convex-polygon

I need to cut a convex not simple polygon by two perpendicular lines to divide it into 4 equal(area) parts.

[image: example]

I wrote a program, but it does not pass tests.

- I think the reason is rounding errors or my function of calculating area.
- Please check it, is it correct?
- I use shoelace algorithm and heron's formula

Here is the code:

```
double calcArea() {
    double result = 0;
    if (size() > 4) {
        int j = size() - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < size() - 1; i++) {
            result += (points.get(i).getX() + points.get(j).getX())
                    *
                    (points.get(j).getY() - points.get(i).getY());
            j = i;
        }
        result = result / (result >= 0 ? 2. : -2.);
    }  else if(size() == 3) {
        double c,a,b, p;
        c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(points.get(0).getY()-points.get(1).getY(),2)+Math.pow(points.get(0).getX()-points.get(1).getX(),2));
        a = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(points.get(1).getY()-points.get(2).getY(),2)+Math.pow(points.get(1).getX()-points.get(2).getX(),2));
        b = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(points.get(0).getY()-points.get(2).getY(),2)+Math.pow(points.get(0).getX()-points.get(2).getX(),2));
        p = (a + b + c) / 2.;
        return Math.sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c));

    }


    return result;
}
```

What I do in:

- finding of `point(x, y)` of cutting polygon.
- I cut it by `x = a in [ min(x), max(x)]`
- and calculate `S'`(part of polygon from x=min(x) to x=a)
- if `S' = S/2` , i take `a` for calculating value`(a, *)`
- then the same with `y = b` where`b in [min(y), max(y)]`
- Is there more fast method?

Comment: I assume you do not know which tests fail and therefore can not reproduce the error? You could try to come up with small examples and hope that the code fails on them. If you think floating point arithmtic is the issue (which is very possible), you could use `BigDecimal` instead of `double`.

Comment: Are you missing a case for `size() == 4`?

Comment: just a silly suggestion but did you take in mind that the lines will most likely not going through vertexes most of the time (unlike on your image)? and also you did not specify space but from code I assume 2D. (if polygon is in 3D then you need to change equation or use its plane coordinate system. if the polygon is not symmetrical then you need 3 perpendicular lines not two !!!